# Send error Status codes to front end from ApolloServer GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I have this simple Apollo Server GraphQL running on Node, i want that every time i get something like 401 or any other error that GQL gets from `formatError`, send that error status to Front End, because now FE always receives 200 even if there is an error

```
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  serviceList,
})

const server = new ApolloServer({
  gateway,
  formatError: (err: GraphQLError) => {
    return new ApolloError(err.message, err.extensions.code, err.extensions)
  },
})
```

I have now that every time error is thrown `formatError` will return that error object to FE but i need to change response status code also instead of that being 200 all the time.

Answer (score 0):

In GraphQL [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors#returning-http-status-codes):

> GraphQL, by design, does not use the same conventions from REST to communicate via HTTP verbs and status codes.

Said that then, You can create a plugin according to the established flow [Link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins#request-lifecycle-event-flow):

```
import { GraphQLRequestContext } from 'apollo-server-types'

export default async function({ response, errors }: GraphQLRequestContext) {
    if (errors?.length) {
        // @ts-ignore
        response.http.status = errors[0].extensions.code
    }
}
```

From the above, it's important to add the `@ts-ignore` statement because it's an optional response statement in the `GraphQLRequestContext` interface.

Comment: What type of event is this in request lifecycle event flow?